# Lifting of continuous group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $P$, $G$, and $H$ be Lie groups along with a *continuous surjective* homomorphism $\pi: G\to H$. Suppose there exists a continuous homomorphism $f: P\to H$. I want to know, under what conditions, $f$ can be lifted to a map $s: P \to G$ such that $\pi*s=f$. Of course, if there is an injection $m: H \to G$ then we already have a lift. But is it a necessary condition?
I don't understand how to approach the problem. If someone can give some hints that will be very helpful.

Comment: In general this is  a bit complicated, see [obstruction theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstruction_theory). <> Your set-up is a (special type of) principal bundle $\pi:G \to H$ with fibre $K = \ker\pi$. If $\widetilde{P}$ is the universal cover of $P$, then $f$ induces a mapping $\tilde{f}:\widetilde{P} \to H$. In order for your mapping $s$ to exist, it's necessary (but not sufficient) that $\tilde{f}$ lift to $\tilde{s}:\widetilde{P} \to G$. Studying _that_ lifting is obstruction theory on the pullback of $\pi:G \to H$ to $\widetilde{P}$ by $\tilde{f}$.